# Regular Expression for identity number in office 365

Tags: regex, office365

I'm currently creating a custom regex for kenyan ID numbers, usually the ID number consists of eight digits, the first two digits is constant, but changes with time. Example of an ID number: `34640970`. So the mentioned ID is within `34` series.

Other series is:
`20` series
`20456880, 20337228, 20656902`
`32` series
`32879776, 32877009, 32344112`
`34` series
`34640970, 34434229, 34223007`

Have managed to write the following regex to be used by office 365 DLP for `34` series, but its not working.
`^(\d{3,4})\d{8}`

Comment: Would all numbers always be 8 digits?  Or, could the number of digits vary?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the total digits remains eight

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked, thank you. Now i understand if i need to add more series, its just append a pipe with the series constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
\b(?:34|32|20)[0-9]{6}\b
(?<!\d)(?:34|32|20)[0-9]{6}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CxNgRe/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary / `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand numeric boundary
- `(?:34|32|20)` - a non-capturing group matching either `34`, `32` or `20` (you can factor it in as `(?:3[42]|20)`)
- `[0-9]{6}` - six digits
- `\b` - word boundary / `(?!\d)` - a right-hand numeric boundary.